# symfony jQuery keyup strange situation

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have simple comment form . I put char-counter . When i create new comment all work fine. When i try to edit comment ,char-counter doesnt work.I tried whit Live(), but result is the same. Other Js in edit page is work fine, just this keyup function is die. I tried to put alert to see whether keyup works, but no responce. 
Here is my code:

- html

  ```
      <?php echo form_tag_for($form, '@comments',array('class' => 'nice'));?>

          <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields() ?>
          <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors() ?>
          <?php echo $form['_csrf_token']; ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="comments[users_id]" id="comments_users_id" value="1" />
          <input type="hidden" name="comments[tests_id]" id="comments_users_id" value="<?php echo $testId?>" />


          <?php echo $form['comment']->renderError() ?>

            <div class="count">remaining symbols : 250</div>
            <div class="barbox"><div class="bar"></div></div>

          <?php echo $form['comment']->render(array('class' => 'comments_comment')) ?>

          <?php  echo $form['captcha']->renderLabel(null,array('class' => 'label-login-down ')) ?>
          <?php echo $form['captcha']->renderError() ?>
          <?php echo $form['captcha']->render(array('class' => 'normal  input-text ' , 'placeholder'=>"Въведете символите")) ?>

          <input type="submit" name="addComment" value="Изпрати" />          
      </form>
  ```
- jquery

  ```
  $(".comments_comment").keyup(function()
  {       
    var box=$(this).val();
    var main = box.length *100;
    var value= (main / 250);
    var count= 250 - box.length;

    if(box.length <= 250)
    { 
      if(box.length <=210)
      {
       $('.count').html('remaining symbols : '+count);            
      }
      else
      {          
     $('.count').html('<div class="commentAlertSymbols">remaining symbols :    '+count+'</div>'); 
      }
    $('.bar').animate(
    {
    "width": value+'%',
    }, 1);

  }
  else
  {
    $('.count').html('<div class="commentRedSymbols">remaining symbols : '+count+'</div>');
  }
  return false;
  });
  ```

Comment: Does the `edit` and `new` template use the same form render ? Does your `comments` textarea realy have the class `.comments_comment` when you edit a comment?

Comment: Yes bouth forms is exacly the same .comments_comment and other css classes exist in the bouth. I use two forms .  I use two becose new comment is build  in another module.

Comment: So you are using the same form render for two forms (the one for create and the one for edit) ? Is the JS included in both render ?

Comment: I update form in post. I use this form for edit and new , and routing do everiting . Yes i tink js is includet in the edit form becose emoticons and other js tinks works fine . They are in the same js file whit keyup function.I doesn't have js errors in brouser console log

Comment: You "think" js is included? Double check the code :) If you keyup doesn't work neither your alert, it seems your js isn't loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been nice to see the actual form HTML output instead of all those PHP helper functions, but I'll give it a shot:

```
$('.comments_comment').keyup(function() {
    // Get the number of characters, percent used, and number left
    var $count = $('.count');
    var chars = $(this).val().length;
    var percent = (chars / 250) * 100;
    var left = 250 - chars;

    // Update the counter
    $count.html('Remaining Symbols: ' + left);

    // Add classes based on how many are left
    if (chars > 210 && chars <= 250) {
        $count.addClass('commentAlertSymbols');
    } else if (chars > 250) {
        $count.addClass('commentRedSymbols');
    }

    // Animate the bar
    $('.bar').css({
        width: chars <= 250 ? percent + '%' : '100%'
    });
});
```

I made the code more DRY. Also, I changed the `$('.bar').animate` line to `$('.bar').css`, because I didn't see the point of animating something over one second.

You can see a working JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/KjTrj/.

Comment: Heh it works !! :)) Тhank you :)) You save me couple of hours :)